# How to get OTCSticket with api/v1/auth method=post in content server using c#

Tags: c#

Following is the API Call i make using postman and get a ticket back in the response body (screenshot):

[image]

I am not able to get the ticket in a HttpWebRequest Response in C#. Please below see the small sample code:

**C# code**

```
HttpWebRequest Request = WebRequest.Create(strUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
Request.Method = "POST";
Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic <>");
//Request.ContentType = "application/form-data";

Request.KeepAlive = true;

string data = string.Format("username=" + UserName + "&password=" + Password);
byte[] dataStream = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
Request.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;

using (Stream newStream = Request.GetRequestStream())
{
    // Send the data.
    newStream.Write(dataStream, 0, dataStream.Length);
    newStream.Close();
}

var Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();
using (var stream = Response.GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    if (Response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        throw new Exception("The request did not complete successfully and returned status code " + Response.StatusCode);

    ResponseTicket strTicket= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseTicket>(reader.ToString());
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Response.GetResponseStream().ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(strTicket.Ticket);
}
```

Where as `statuscode=200`. But the content length is 0.
It is very difficult to find any meaning full help on CS10.5 API. I have checked there AppWorks platform but in vain. Would appreciate if someone can find the problem in the code, which apparently i can not see.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still an issue for you. For me it was also, but figured it out:

```
            public string LoginAsAdminAndRetrieveTicket(string userName, string passWord, string domain, string url)
    {
        var uri = $"http://{url}/otcs/llisapi.dll/api/v1/auth";

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.Headers.Add("Connection", new[] { "Keep-Alive" });
        request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        request.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        request.Content = new StringContent($"username={userName};password={passWord}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy(),
            UseProxy = true,
            AllowAutoRedirect = true
        };

        using (var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
        {
            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
            string ticket;
            var vals = response.Headers.TryGetValues("OTCSTicket", out IEnumerable<string> temp) ? temp : new List<string>();
            if (vals.Any())
            {
                ticket = vals.First();
            }

            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
```